# Hough Transform Not working

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect circles from the image using hough transform
my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Anmol/Desktop/your_file.bmp")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2,10)        

cv2.waitKey(0)

print (circles)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
# convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers

circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

# loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
for (x, y, r) in circles:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.rectangle(output, (x -5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

stops at the line

```
 circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2,10)
```

I left my code running for about 5 hours but still its not going ahead of this line. It is not giving any error.

Plzz guide me what to do.

Comment: If you're using an IDE like PyCharm, you can put a breakpoint at that line and then step through all the third-party code until you find the exact place where progress gets blocked.

Comment: debugger is still no showing whats going on inside at that step

Comment: the link to my image is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-SMLCVNyji1ejlRMnlSVHRrRXc

Answer (score 0):

I suggest downscaling the input image if it's really large, and running a blur filter.  Both of these will speed up Hough tremendously.